# Removendo todos os espaços de uma string usando Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Gostaria de saber se tem uma maneira de remover todos os espaços em branco num texto usando Javascript.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você pode utilizar REGEX para realizar tal ação, segue exemplo de código:

```js
var strDefault = 'Te s te de remo ção de es pa ço s';

document.querySelector('.default').innerHTML = strDefault;

var str = strDefault.replace(/\s/g, '');

document.querySelector('.new').innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<h1 class="default"></h1>

<br>

<h1 class="new"></h1>
```

Recomendo a utilização do \s para remoção dos espaços pois ele removerá qualquer tipo de caractere que represente um espaço em branco, por exemplo: *'\t\r\n'*;

O REGEX é bem útil em casos que você precise de um padrão dinâmico, seria uma boa dar uma pesquisada mais a fundo sobre o assunto.

Comment: Obrigado funcionou como eu queria.